# decode json in php and get each array value

Tags: php, json

I'm new in php I have a json I decoded it and wrote the following

```
$jsonInput = '[{"b_pag_bo_id":"31","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"1","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"3","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"31","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"2","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"57","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"31","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"3","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"60","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"4","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"4","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"5","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"6","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"6","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"9","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"7","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"183","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"8","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"324","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"9","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"331","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"32","b_pag_user_id":"1","b_pag_id":"10","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"710","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"34","b_pag_user_id":"0","b_pag_id":"11","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"50","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"34","b_pag_user_id":"0","b_pag_id":"12","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"99","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"26","b_pag_user_id":"0","b_pag_id":"13","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"5","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"},{"b_pag_bo_id":"26","b_pag_user_id":"0","b_pag_id":"14","b_page_mark":"1","b_pag_num":"7","b_pag_note":"","b_page_stop":"1"}]';

$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput, true);

print_r($decoded);
```

and the result is in the link [here](http://dt-works.com/eman/bookMarks2.php)

I want to get each value of each key meaning I want all `b_pag_bo_id` & others in a separate variables.  How do I do that?

Comment: Any reason you prefer separate variables over one big array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print values similar to this:

```
foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['b_pag_bo_id'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it gives me the values without separators, how can I separate them by spaces for example?

Comment: `echo $value['b_pag_bo_id'] . ", "; ` that 'll add comma separator.

Comment: $last_item = array_pop($decoded); echo $last_item['b_pag_bo_id'];

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop on your result and store the data in individual variables.

```
foreach ( $decoded AS $key => $val ) {
  ${'var'.$key} = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop though array:

```php
$b_pag_bo_id = array();
$b_pag_user_id = array();
foreach ($decoded as $item) {
   $b_pag_bo_id[] = $item['b_pag_bo_id'];
   $b_pag_user_id[] = $item['b_pag_user_id'];
}
```

Comment: You said that you want it in variable. If you want to print it you can use this `echo implode(', ', $b_pag_bo_id);` or `echo json_encode($b_pag_bo_id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array['playerCredentials'] as $key => $value) 
{
   printf('%s => %s<br />', $key, $value);
}
```